# Unable to login from facebook social auth in my django application

Tags: django, python-3.x, facebook

I have developed an application in Django and I want to use the facebook authentication in my application.

For this, I add social_django in my app. Then I create the application login application on facebook developer.

In basic settings I put following:

**App Name:** mywebsite_name

**Privacy Policy URL: https://mydomain(domain has ssl certificate)

**Site URL**: **https://mydomain**

In the facebook login App setting:

**Client OAuth Login :** yes

**Web OAuth Login:** yes

**Enforce HTTPS:** yes

Force Web OAuth Reauthentication: No

**Embedded Browser OAuth Login:** Yes

**Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs:** Yes

**Valid OAuth Redirect URIs :**https://mydomain/login/callback

**Login from Devices :** No

I have also added my appid and app secret in settings.py file as using .env file

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = config('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY')
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = config('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET')

In the urls.py file I do this:

```
 <p><a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">Continue With Facebook</a> </p>
```

But unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
Insecure login blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https:// ?
```

And again note I have https domain name Please help me to remove this error.